# PHPStorm crashes for no apparent reason

Tags: crash, phpstorm

I am using PHPStorm 9 and crashes all the time. 
I checked for logs but it does not report anything. 
What can I do to debug it?

**Edit 1**
The app is fresly installed, on freshly formated PC, with fresh installed and updated java. 
Also I tried to increase the allocated RAM but each time the app starts returns my values to default.

**Edit 2**
I am using the 64bit version which demanded an external jdk since there wasn't provided by the app.
I installed the 8.60 X64 java and add to my user and system vars on windows 10.

**Edit 3**
I am using Eset's nod32. 
This is a notice that shows when I load the app.
[image]

Comment: It should produce some logs -- if not IDE itself then on system level (app crash is not ordinary situation). 1) Disable all 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins 2) Reinstall app 3) Backup and delete your IDE config and start from scratch (you may then recover most of your config files from backup) 4) Have you tried restarting your computer? 5) Reinstall or try another Java version 6) Could also be memory problems (test your RAM)

Comment: @LazyOne I updated my answer. Please check it out and tell me how to test my rams.

Comment: So .. you have a Windows there? On Windows it comes with own bundled JDK which it uses by default and you have to manually specify (trough some environment variables) that you want to use your own Java version. As for RAM test -- this option is available when you booting your PC (assuming you have Windows) -- it's one of the options next to Safe Boot (available since Vista). Also -- try temporarily disabling any antivirus apps.

Comment: @LazyOne Re edited. Please have another look.

Comment: If you did all what I was suggesting .. then I'm out of ideas (plus, I'm still on Windows 7). I may just only suggest to use Event Viewer and check what it may have there. I do not know what the path on Win10 .. but on Win7 you can use "View reliability history" in Action Centre to see all app crashes and other similar important info.

Comment: Other than that: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: @LazyOne I also had this problem on Windows 7

Comment: Your latest screenshot suggests that project settings are corrupted somehow (first suggestion: those files have BOM header while they should not). I suggest deleting that `.idea` subfolder (while IDE is closed) and reconfigure project from scratch (use "Open" from Welcome screen and point it to project root folder).

Comment: @LazyOne I deleted the faulty files and I am waiting to see if there is a result.